# How to make table row at server side visible using javascript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, c#-4.0

I am making a tr which runs at server side to invisible. But in some conditions,I want it to be visible.I am using the bellow script to make it visible:

```
 document.getElementById('trID').style.display = "block"
```

and also i used:

```
  document.getElementById('hidebuttons').style.visibility = "visible";
```

But it is not working.
Please help me on this.

Comment: how did you set it `invisible`?

Comment: From the server side. "trID.visible=False;"

Comment: yes... but which property did you set?

Comment: can you post the resulting html code?

Comment: rowid.row.Style.Add("display", "none"); try this in serverside and then in client  side try something like you had done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once control is marked as invisible at server side, no mark-up (html) is emitted for it. So it cannot be made visible at JS, because it (corresponding html) does not exists at client side.

you can do something like

```
trID.Attributes.Add("style", "display:none");
```

then in javascript

```
document.getElementById('trID').style.display = "block"
```

**NOTE**: If you set the control `visible=false`  in server side then it will not render at client side